# AttributeError: "AbstractModel" object has no attribute "computeIIS"

Tags: python, gurobi, pyomo

I have a Stochastic Mixed Integer Problem where some of the scenarios may give infeasible issues.

The model is formulated as an Abstract Pyomo Model and the solver I'm using is gurobi 8.1.0

I want to see the Irreducible Inconsistent Subsystem (IIS) so I could fix my infallibility problems.

In the link below is the function I'm trying to use, model.computeIIS().

http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_computeiis.html

I have tried copy pasting from time link above and implemented the code below (http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/examples.pdf , workforce1.py page 401)

```
model.computeIIS()
     if model.IISMinimal :
         print("IIS is minimal \n")
     else :
         print ("IIS is not minimal \n")
         print ("\ n The following constraint (s) cannot be satisfied:")

for c in model.getConstrs():
     if c.IISConstr:
     print ("%s" % c.constrName)
```

I hoped that this would have printed the IIS. Unfortunately, it just gives me the Attribute Error:"AbstractModel" object has no attribute "computeISS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model seems to be a Pyomo model, but the example is using the Gurobi Model class. The Pyomo class does not have the method `computeIIS`.

The `GurobiDirect` class accepts some Gurobi parameters, including `ResultFile`. The following will make Gurobi write an IIS to a file:

```
opt = SolverFactory('gurobi')
opt.options['ResultFile'] = "test.ilp"
```

The suffix of the filename determines the type of the result file; `.ilp` is for IISs. [See here.](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/resultfile.html)

Comment: Tried: opt.options['iisfind'] = 1
Returned: No parameters matching "iisfind" found 

Have tried implementing the example you sent. Did not work. Could it be that Im using gurobi 8.1.0, and not gurobi ampl?

Comment: You are right. I also cannot get this to work with solver "gurobi". I found another way and modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. 
Is there a way to print the IIS computed constraint directly?

Comment: I searched the Pyomo source code and couldn't find any direct way. (The one in the example uses Ampl.) It looks like you would have to read and parse the `.ilp` file from your Python code.